# Buscar diferencias entre días SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

os adjunto un ejemplo de lo que me gustaría.
Me gustaría sacar la diferencia de "Compensación" entre dos fechas para un empleado.
Por ejemplo: ver la diferencia para el ID 1 entre el día 5 y el 6.

Uso una SQLite y me gustaría saber cómo sacar esas diferencias con una query
He probado esto pero no funciona:

```
SELECT (compensation FROM tabla WHERE dia=5 AND id=5)-(compensation FROM table WHERE dia=6 AND id=5)
```

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en una consulta sin tabla con dos sub-consultas a la tabla de tu interés, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  (select compensation FROM tabla WHERE dia=5 AND id=5)
       -(select compensation FROM tabla WHERE dia=6 AND id=5) Diferencia
```

Si tienes una tabla de empleados y quieres obtener la diferencia de todos, puedes aplicar una técnica similar, pero correlacionando las sub-consultas con tu tabla de empleados, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT Empleado.Id
       ,  (select tabla.compensation FROM tabla WHERE tabla.dia=5 AND tabla.id=Empleado.id)
         -(select tabla.compensation FROM tabla WHERE tabla.dia=6 AND tabla.id=empleado.id) Diferencia
  from Empleado
```

Comment: gracias!! muy útil tu respuesta

Answer (score -1):

algo asi quizas

```
Select dif1=compensation from tabla where id = 1 and day = 5

Select dif2=compensation from tabla where id = 1 and day = 6

set diftot= dif1 - dif2

select diftot
```

Comment: No he especificado, pero era en SQLite que no me permite crear variables como tal. Sabrías cómo hacerlo? He leído que con WITH podría pero no sé cómo aplicarlo a este caso

Comment: puedes ver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it